# Player Object spins continuously when moving joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a twin stick movement system for mobile. I have a character moving under the influence of one joystick correctly. The other joystick, the design I want is:

When the shoot JS is moved, look in that direction.

When the shoot JS is released, shoot in the last aimed direction.

What's happening is, the character shoots continuously when the game starts and if I move the ShootJS, the character spins in circles. I'm completely flummoxed as to why this is happening.
Here is my code. Thanks in advance to anybody for any help you provide.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using Ludiq;
using Bolt;



public class PlayerJSControlSc : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public NavMeshAgent nav;
    public Text stateText;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Animator animator;
    public FloatingJoystick moveJS;
    public FloatingJoystick shootJS;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10;
    public int ammo;
    public int mag;
    public Transform shotSpawn;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public float reloadTime;
    public Text ammoCount;
    [HideInInspector]
    int currentMag;

   

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        stateText.text = "";
        nav = player.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
        moveJS = GameObject.Find("Floating JS_Move").GetComponent<FloatingJoystick>();
        shootJS = GameObject.Find("Floating JS_Shoot").GetComponent<FloatingJoystick>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movePlayer();
        playerShoot();
        ammoCount.text = currentMag+ "/" + ammo;
    }

    public void movePlayer()
    {
        //float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float x = moveJS.Horizontal;
        float y = moveJS.Vertical;
        nav.velocity = new Vector3(x * moveSpeed, 0, y * moveSpeed);
        if (nav.velocity.x != 0 || nav.velocity.z != 0)
        { animator.SetBool("isRunning", true); }
        else { animator.SetBool("isRunning", false); }
       
    }


   
    public void playerShoot()
    {
        bool isAiming = false;
        float x = shootJS.Horizontal; float z = shootJS.Vertical;
            if (x != 0 || z != 0)
            {
                isAiming = true;
                /* Vector3 lookDir = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
                 Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDir, Vector3.up);
                 float step = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                 player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(lookRotation, transform.rotation, step);*/
                float myAngle = Mathf.Atan2(x, z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                float bodyRotation = myAngle + player.transform.eulerAngles.y;
            player.transform.Rotate( 0,myAngle,0,Space.World);

            }
        else { shoot();isAiming = false; }
        }

       void shoot()
        {
            if (currentMag > 0)
            {
                Instantiate(bullet, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
                currentMag--;
            }
            else if (currentMag=0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(reload());
            }
            else
                return;

        }


    IEnumerator reload()
    {
        
        ammo = ammo - mag;
        currentMag = mag;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you are calling **every frame** `playerShoot()` -> not moving -> `shoot()`.

And in the same way also `playerShoot()` -> not moving -> `player.transform.Rotate( 0,myAngle,0,Space.World);`.

---

I think what you rather should do is

- doing the `shoot` only in the very first frame where both inputs are `0`
- for the move rather set the rotation instead of increasing it

Something like

```
private bool lastFrameMoved;

public void playerShoot()
{
    float x = shootJS.Horizontal; 
    float z = shootJS.Vertical;
    if (x != 0 || z != 0)
    {
        var lookDir = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        var lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDir, Vector3.up);
         player.transform.rotation = lookRotation;

        lastFrameMoved = true;
    }
    else 
    { 
        if(lastFrameMoved)
        {
            shoot();
        }

        lastFrameMoved = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the look rotation in Bolt (because it helps me visualize). I'll solve the shoot part soon. I'm using the wonderful Joystick Pack by Fenerax Studios.
https://assetstore.unity.com/publishers/32730